# How should I theme a drupal custom field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

**Drupal 7**

I have made a custom field named 'headline', it machine name hence is `field_headline`.

Now, I have created a file named `field--field_headline.tpl.php`, but I do not know what should I do in my custom `node.tpl.php` template, in this file, I do:

```
<?php
print render($field_headline);
?>
```

But it does print nothing. The `$field_headline` structure is:

```
$field_headline => 'und' => 0 => {
   'value' => "some value',
   'safe_value' => 'some_value',
   ...
};
```

How should I print the field in drupal then? Because drupal needs to know if the field has a custom template (in case of mine, it has).

Comment: Can you not use simple css for that single field instead of writing custom theme template?

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this :

```
<?php
print(render($content ['field_headline']));
?>
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7

> $content: An array of node items. Use render($content) to print them all, or print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a given element.